# Proof that a function is unbounded

Tags: functions

I have this function
\begin{equation*}
f(x):=\left\{\begin{array}{cl} \frac{3}{2}x^{\frac{1}{2}}(\sin\frac{1}{x})+x^{\frac{3}{2}}(\cos\frac{1}{x})(-x^{-2}), & \mbox{for }0<x\leq 1,\\ 0, & \mbox{for } x=0. \end{array}\right. 
\end{equation*}
How can I show that $f$ is unbounded on the Interval $[0,1]$?

Comment: The trigonometric functions are bounded, the powers may not be...

Comment: Can you precise what is inside the $\cos$ function?

Comment: @Jean-PierreMerx $\frac{1}{x}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is unbounded. Take the sequence $(\frac{1} {n \pi} ) $.